# mysql concat data if null to end and if not null to continue concat

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I've used stack over flow before with my sql questions and was successful.

This time I may not be as successful with my next issue.

I have a table we will call `Statements_1` that has around 50 columns and lets say 10,000 rows.

Each column has either a statement in it like "my dog runs" or the column is null.

The columns are labeled as 1, 2, 3, etc up until 50.

As well as the rows all start with simple pk's starting with 1 up until 10,000.

The data is not consistent in length on each row of the table.

For example row #1 has a statement in 5 consecutive columns, row #2 has a statement in 37 consecutive columns, row #3 has a statement in 19 consecutive columns, etc.

What I need to do is write some simple code that would create an html format bullet type paragraph using the statements into table Statements_2 column Bullet. ex:

my dog runs 
14 apples taste good
yes this is fun
I am wasting my resources

I understand how to just concat the whole row of columns, but it would be a waste of cpu and script run time and ends up leaving a massive amount of white space on the web page that is created where there is null data that would vary depending on how much data is in sum of row columns.

Not only does it waste time, but the memory builds up so fast I have to limit the script to lets say 80 at a time so the server does not lock up and give me a gateway timeout after I overload the memory usage.

Any advice on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT id, 
       CONCAT_WS(' ', 
                 COALESCE(col1, ''),
                 COALESCE(col2, ''),
                 COALESCE(col3, ''),
                 COALESCE(col4, ''),
                 COALESCE(col5, '')) bullet
  FROM Statements_1
```

Output:

```
| ID |                    BULLET |
----------------------------------
|  1 | my dog runs               |
|  2 | 14 apples taste good      |
|  3 | yes this is fun           |
|  4 | I am wasting my resources |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75a9c/1)** demo

[`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns the first non-NULL value from the list. In the example if a column value is NULL it returns an empty string otherwise the value itself.
Now [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) is a convinient way to concatenate a bunch of values with a separator.

Comment: Could you explain what concat_ws does? as well as coalesce? Ive never used either variation before. Also SQLFiddle is so usefull!

Comment: @Chris See the updated answer for some explanation. If it was what you were looking for please, consider to [`accept`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.

Comment: @Chris Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Glad to hear that! Did the answer help in any way?